# Read struct from binary file using read

Tags: c, file, struct

I'm doing a simple operation over a complex client/server (multi chating rooms) program in C.

I've a linkedlist structure called ***node***

```
struct node
{
    char *user;
    char *passwd;
    int id;
    int connected;
    struct node *next;
};
```

And another structure called ***room***

```
struct room
{
    char *name;
    int capacity;
    int room_id;
    int admin_id;
    struct room *next;
    struct node *users;
};
```

I declare this as a global variable:

```
struct room *rooms = NULL;
```

I've already protected it with mutex and semaphores.

So I just want to write this structure when the server ends and then load it later when the server starts again. The logic of doing that resides in two files, ***server.c*** and ***server_utils.c*** as I'm showing below:

***server.c***:

```
int main (void)
{
    [...]
    struct stat st;
    [...]
    stat ("rooms.bin", &st);
    if (st.st_size > 0)
    {
        // Load rooms
        load_rooms ();
    }
    else
    {
        [...]
    }
    [...]
    exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

***server_utils.c***:

```
[...]

void load_rooms (void)
{
    int fd;
    if ((fd = open ("rooms.bin", O_RDONLY)) < 0)
    {
        perror ("open");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        read (fd, &rooms, sizeof (rooms));
    }
}

void save_rooms (void)
{
    int fd;
    if ((fd = open ("rooms.bin", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644)) < 0)
    {
        perror ("open");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        write (fd, &rooms, sizeof (rooms));
    }
}

[...]
```

The problem I found is that when I read the structure from the binary file with

```
read (fd, &rooms, sizeof (rooms));
```

And then I try to print the structure with

```
void rooms_linkedlist_print (struct room *head)
{
    struct room *curr = head;
    char str[1024];
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        write (1, curr->name, strlen (curr->name));
        write (1, "\n", strlen ("\n"));
        bzero (str, 1024);
        sprintf (str, "%d\n", curr->capacity);
        write (1, str, strlen (str));
        bzero (str, 1024);
        sprintf (str, "%d\n", curr->room_id);
        write (1, str, strlen (str));
        bzero (str, 1024);
        sprintf (str, "%d\n", curr->admin_id);
        write (1, str, strlen (str));
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

I get a segmentation fault (core dumped). Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your room struct has pointers inside it.

These pointers will no longer necessarily point to allocated memory when you reload the data, causing a segmentation fault.

You could fix this by changing from using pointers into using indices into the rooms array.

Comment: I can't change that pointers because I cannot know the lengths so I'm thinking of storing every raw data to a file and then create the structure again with this data values as I'm doing the first time when the file doesn't exists.